# Retrieve Itunes account when performing inapp purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have created an app which allows users to buy non-consumable content. The retrieving-ids-payment-process works like a charm but i wish too, when the transaction is completed and the request is made to download the content, I would like to save who has downloaded this content.
In my observer i have implemented method:

```
- (void)completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction");
    [[ShopHandler sharedManager] provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier]; 
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; 
}
```

In my ShopHandler i have the provideContent method

```
-(void) provideContent: (NSString*) productIdentifier {
    Here i want to retrieve the user that has bought this product and
    then perform a request to my server
    e.g http://www.tesserver.com/download?id=com.my.id.test&itunesid=test@itunes.com
 }
```

So how do i retrieve that itunes id?

**Edit:**

Apple states in their Introducing Store Kit video in the iPhone Dev Center one we should:

> "Keep a copy of the TransactionID along with the Customer Information in your server in the cloud. This way if the customer mistakenly deletes your application, you have a mechanism for recovery. You can check your server on first launch of your app for a record of the purchases for a given customer and bring that app back to its state before it was deleted. Believe me your customers will be thankful!"

So what do they mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can. This is a security feature, and furthermore as a user I don't want you to know my iTunes ID.

Comment: I think by "Customer information" they mean things like UDIDs and receipts. I don't see any methods that expose iTunes usernames.

Comment: Ok I understand, what you are saying make sense! Thank you for your answer